# Using asp-for TagHelper in Partial Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've created a ViewComponent to show Popups in my WebApp, this VC is only used as a shell for html (using bootstrap modals) and the popup content is loaded via javascrit from a Partial Page.

When I try to use asp-for tag helpers in the content of the partial, I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'viewData')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression[TModel,TValue]
(ViewDataDictionary`1 viewData, Expression`1 expression)
```

I've already added the `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` to the page, because I thought thah ViewImports weren't been loaded.

These are the files used:

```cs
<!-- Pages/Shared/Components/Popup/default.cshtml -->
@model App.ViewComponents.PopupViewModel

<div class="modal @Model.CssClasses" id="@Model.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@Model.LabeledBy" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@Model.Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $('#@Model.Id').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $.get("@Model.ContentPage",
            null,
            data => {
                $("#@Model.Id").modal("show");
                $("#@Model.Id .modal-body").html(data);
            });
    })
</script>
```

```cs
// ViewComponents/Popup.cs
namespace App.ViewComponents
{
    public class Popup : ViewComponent
    {
        public Popup()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(PopupViewModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    public class PopupViewModel
    {
        public PopupViewModel()
        {

        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ContentPage { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string SubTitle { get; set; }
        public string CssClasses { get; set; }
        public string LabeledBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm loading the popup content (the ajax calls this from the VC):

```cs
public PartialViewResult OnGetCreate()
{
    var createPageModel = new CreateModel();
    return Partial("Create", createPageModel);
}
```

And this is the content of the partial:

```
@page
@model App.Pages.CreateModel
@{
}


<form method="post">
    <!-- This works -->
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InputModel.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.InputModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

    <!-- This don't work -->
    <label asp-for="InputModel.Description"></label>
    <input asp-for="InputModel.Description" />
})

    <button id="submit" asp-page-handler="New" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</form>
```

Anyone has any clue about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @page on the top of the partial is null, which is causing this error.